# Flex Items Spilling, not Resizing

Tags: css, flexbox

https://codepen.io/fluark/pen/VwxGawr

```
.header  {
  display: flex;
  font-family: monospace;
  background: papayawhip;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-left: auto; 
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  background: papayawhip;
  gap: 10em;
  list-style-type: none;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

[Desired Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIpJH.png)

Visually my header looks fairly close to the desired outcome, however when I shrink down the page, the right links/ul  (child items) spill out of the header (parent).

I am pretty sure this is a matter of not having the proper flex settings. **Is the error maybe in the flex-basis? Or potentially the relationship between flex-shrink and flex-basis?**

I have looked up flex settings and tried separately adding “flex: 1;” on both the parent .header as well as the div.right-links and ul.

I have also tried creating a separate div... div.header and then adding flex: 1 to that with the intention of making it so the parent is able to grow when the window is resized. That didn't seem to do anything.

I am a little confused because with “display: flex” on both the .header element and the ul, that means the flex-shrink is 1 (flex = 0, 1, auto), **so shouldn’t the links be shrinking when the parent element is resized, not spilling out?**

I’m looking for some guidance/talk throughs because I am at the point where I am just adding to the code to “see what happens”, and that’s when I know I need help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you wanting 'one', 'two' and 'three' to stack on top of each other or be side by side?

Comment: I am looking for them to be side by side.

file:///Users/hmcdaniel/repos/css-exercises/flex/02-flex-header/desired-outcome-narrow.png

This is the desired outcome.

Comment: You might have to edit your original post and upload the image to there. I can't access that link as it's not to any domain.

Comment: Right, sorry about that. I put it in the post! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ul element has a default padding of 26px and when you narrow the viewport it's that padding that's pushing the div to the right. If you set padding-left: to 0 then it removes it. I've also set the li display type to inline-block so that the padding on the a element does not overflow the logo on small screen sizes. At really small screen sizes (below 612px or so), the logo, a tags, gaps and padding will all be the lowest they can be so if you want to restyle it any further then I'd use a media query. See below

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: monospace;
  background: papayawhip;
  padding: 5px;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: tomato;
  background: white;
  padding: 4px 32px;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  flex-direction: row;
  /* this removes the dots on the list items*/
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  font-size: 22px;
  background: white;
  /* this removes the line under the links */
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="left-links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">ONE</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">TWO</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">THREE</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
  <div class="right-links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">FOUR</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">FIVE</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SIX</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "The ul element has a default padding of 26px and when you narrow the viewport it's that padding that's pushing the div to the right."

Ah!! Okay, that is a helpful piece of info. Did you determine this by inspecting with devtools?

Also, if I were to set that padding to 0, is there a way to keep from overflowing without setting the element to inline block?

Thank you!!

Comment: Yep, used the dev tools. The ul item is a flex item because it's a child of the .header div. I set the li element from display:list-item to display:inline-block because otherwise the anchor tag padding would then overflow the parent element and the buttons would overflow each other.